# Отслеживать время выполнения ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Как отслеживать, сколько длится ajax запрос. Ясно, что есть `timeout`, но он устанавливает максимальное время выполнения.

Мне же нужно, если запрос выполняется больше 1 секунды, например, показать заглушку - крутящуюся штуковину. Обычно запросы проходят быстро. И чтобы при каждой отправке мигала "крутёлка" - это не дело. А вот если запрос по какой-то причине выполняется долго, то было бы хорошо оповестить пользователя - показать "крутёлку". Как это сделать?

Т.е. как показать "крутёлку" не сразу после начала запроса, а через какое-то время?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'url',
    async: 'false',
    timeout: 20000,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: data,
    success: function(result){message(result);},
    error: function(err){console.log(err);}
});
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    jQuery('.animationload').addClass('hide'); //прячу крутёлку
});
```

Comment: В смысле отменить запрос? Или показывать таймер?

Comment: показать "крутёлку". Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Ну и используйте крутилку через секунду если ответ не пришел, убираете её если выполнен always у ajax запроса. Или у Вас вопрос как сделать крутилку?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик Вопрос - как показать крутёлку не сразу после запуска запроса, а через какое-то время.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ifResponse = false;
$.ajax(...).always(function() {
  ifResponse =true; 
  $('.animationload').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
});

setTimeout(function(){ 
  if (!ifResponse) 
    $('.animationload').removeClass('hide').addClass('show'); 
}, 1000);
```

естественно это работает только при одном асинхронном запросе! Если Вам надо выполнять несколько запросов тут подойдет такой метод:

```
var countResponse = 0;//!!!!Глобальная переменная!!!!

function Send() {
  ++countResponse;
  $.ajax(...).always(function() {
    --countResponse;
    if (countResponse <= 0)
      $('.animationload').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
  });

  setTimeout(function(){ 
    if (countResponse > 0) 
      $('.animationload').removeClass('hide').addClass('show'); 
  }, 1000);
}
```

UPD 1 вариант (подсказано Lexx918):

```
let loaderTimer = setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('.animationload').removeClass('hide').addClass('show'); 
}, 1000);

$.ajax(...).always(function() {
  clearTimeout(loaderTimer);
  $('.animationload').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Использую первый вариант. У меня все запросы ajax синхронные - так нужно. Так что два запросы быть не может. Спасибо большое!

Comment: И переменная глобальная и функция и только для одного запроса. Плохо. Легко фиксится выделением в отдельный скоуп: `({var foo = 123; var bar = function(){}; bar(foo);})()`.

Comment: @Lexx918 да, взял Ваш вариант для UPD 1

Answer (score 3):

В `beforeSend` поставьте setTimeout на 1000 миллисекунд и внутри коллбека делайте лоадер видимым, а в `always` clearTimeout и скрывайте лоадер если он виден.
**setTimeout callback** выполняется независимо от основного потока сценария

Answer (score 3):

Стартуем таймер на 1 сек. перед выполнением запроса аяксом. После получения ответа удаляем таймер, а крутилку скрываем независимо от прочих обстоятельств. (+ добавить это дело в коллбек ошибки выполнения запроса)

```
let loaderTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    // показываем крутилку
}, 1000);
$.ajax({
    success: result => {
        clearTimeout(loaderTimer);
        // прячем крутилку (даже если её и не было видно)
    }
});
```

Comment: success надо б на always поменять